# Stop hidden sheets in exporting Excel, VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Macro code that copy's all sheets in my workbook to a new workbook. This works well but the problem is that it copies hidden sheets as well. Can someone help me modify the code so that it copies only the visible sheets.

```
Sub export()

Dim Sht             As Worksheet
Dim DestSht         As Worksheet
Dim DesktopPath     As String
Dim NewWbName       As String
Dim wb              As Workbook
Dim i               As Long

Set wb = Workbooks.Add

DesktopPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\Desktop\"

NewWbName = "report " & Format(Now, "yyyy_mm_dd _hh_mm_ss") & ".xlsx"
i = 1

For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

If i <= wb.Sheets.Count Then
    Set DestSht = wb.Sheets(i)
Else
    Set DestSht = wb.Sheets.Add
End If

Sht.Cells.Copy
With DestSht
    .Cells.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .Cells.PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
    .Name = Sht.Name
End With

i = i + 1
Next Sht

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

wb.SaveAs Filename:=DesktopPath & NewWbName, FileFormat:=51
wb.Close
MsgBox "You Can Find The Exported File In Your Desktop.", vbOKOnly +   vbInformation, "Export Sucessful!"

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use the `Visible` property of the Worksheet object to copy only the visible sheets. If `Sht.Visible = xlSheetVisible` Then ...

Comment: Thanks mate. That did the job it copies only the visible sheets,but it adds a blank sheet in the beginning

Comment: Without seeing your updated code it's hard to tell, but I'm guessing you have the `i = i + 1` code outside of the `If Sht.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then` statement. I've added an answer with updated code which should work OK. I've also added a `Sheet.Move` statement which moves any added sheet to the end of the new workbook. See [https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/107622] for further info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub export()

Dim Sht             As Worksheet
Dim DestSht         As Worksheet
Dim DesktopPath     As String
Dim NewWbName       As String
Dim wb              As Workbook
Dim i               As Long

Set wb = Workbooks.Add

DesktopPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\Desktop\"

NewWbName = "report " & Format(Now, "yyyy_mm_dd _hh_mm_ss") & ".xlsx"

i = 1

    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

        If Sht.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then

            If i <= wb.Sheets.Count Then
                Set DestSht = wb.Sheets(i)
            Else
                Set DestSht = wb.Sheets.Add
                DestSht.Move After:=Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
            End If

            Sht.Cells.Copy
            With DestSht
                .Cells.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
                .Cells.PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
                .Name = Sht.Name
            End With

            i = i + 1

        End If

    Next Sht

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

wb.SaveAs Filename:=DesktopPath & NewWbName, FileFormat:=51
wb.Close
MsgBox "You Can Find The Exported File In Your Desktop.", vbOKOnly +   vbInformation, "Export Sucessful!"

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```